# jQuery click to hide fix

Tags: jquery, html

I need a jquery help in click to to hide issue .

**What I have now :**

I have a text I can click and it will open div . And when I click any place this div hides .also when  I click the Gray div still it's hide

**What I am trying **

I am trying to limit the hiding . IF I click on the Div  it should not hide . beside that clicking other places It will hide .

Live js Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/S4hcf/

**HTML**

```
<p class="show_hide">Clcik Me</p>

<div class="slidingDiv"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div{
width:200px;
height:150px;
background:#ccc;

}

p{
 cursor:pointer;

 }
```

**jQuery**

```
 // click to hide    
$('html').click(function(event){
    if($('.slidingDiv').is(':visible')){
       $('.slidingDiv').hide(); 
    } 
});

//Toggle

$(".slidingDiv").hide();    

$('.show_hide').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
});
```

Any help will be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply prevent the click bubbling up to the outer click when clicking on the div itself:

```
$(".slidingDiv").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4hcf/4/

Comment: Easy solution . Thank you Very much :)

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
$(".slidingDiv").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S4hcf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Add `$(event.target).hasClass('.slidingDiv')` to your condition

```
$('html').click(function(event){
    if($(event.target).hasClass('.slidingDiv') && $('.slidingDiv').is(':visible')){
        $('.slidingDiv').hide(); 
    } 
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/S4hcf/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can initially set the showing `div` to `display:none`

```
      .slidingDiv{
            display:none;
                 }
```

and write the below script for it to `toggle`

```
  $('.show_hide').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();    
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
   });
```

refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/qhXcf/